# Access variable from parent PHP function

Tags: php, function, variables, parent

Is it possible to obtain a variable from a parent function without declaring that function in parenthesis when calling the function (not possible in this instance).

```
function list_posts($filter_by_date){

    /* Dome things to do first 8*/
    function filter(){
        /* Do something that involves the variable $filter_by_date */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use closures:

```
function list_posts($filter_by_date){

    /* Dome things to do first 8*/
    $filter = function() use($filter_by_date) {
        echo $filter_by_date; // outputs "test"

        /* Do something that involves the variable $filter_by_date */
    };

    $filter();
}

list_posts("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, declare them separately and use arguments:

```
function filter($arg){
    echo 'filter() got: ', $arg, PHP_EOL;
}

function list_posts($filter_by_date){

    echo 'list_posts() got: ', $filter_by_date, PHP_EOL;

    filter($filter_by_date);
}

list_posts(date('d.m.Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible if you use a [anonymous function](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php):

```
function list_posts($filter_by_date) {

    // Dome things to do first 8*/
    $filter = function () use($filter_by_date) {
        // Do something that involves the variable $filter_by_date
    };

    // Call the filter function
    $filter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global`.

```
function list_posts($filter_by_date){
    global $filter_by_date;

     // do something with variable
}

function filter(){
    global $filter_by_date;

    echo $filter_by_date;
}
```

Comment: Well, in global scope might be a race conditions. So, in perspective, it is not a reliable approach.

Comment: But it's still another option.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm not downvoted. It only *might* be used **bad**.

Comment: This one doesn't do alas